# Python GTK Issue

Tags: python, gtk

I am having a slight problem with gtk.  I imported it into some python code I wrote awhile back and now whenever I import it, it loads that code on the interpreter. Is there any way to remove that dependency?

```
>>> import gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import gobject as _gobject
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gobject/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/glib/option.py", line 33, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "copy.py", line 42, in <module>
    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'clipboard_get'
```

Thanks

Comment: I was just trying to write some code in the python interpreter, in linux
so just
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
and then it runs an old file

Comment: Sorry but Im not really sure what work you want me to show

Comment: Show the code that leads you to believe that you are seeing the issue that you believe you are seeing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm afraid these won't be such work you require. You see, the problem is just caused by a `import gtk`. Maybe something wrong with the package configurations or so?

Comment: @SteveShell Can I assume you can reproduce this issue by simply open a new terminal with Python, and type `import gtk`, and then this error message would show?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh, then my apologize and let's wait until Steve gives some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called one of your scripts "copy.py", shadowing the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module in the stdlib. Rename it.

Comment: Tried it still getting an error
However I can get gtk to work if I create a new user account but I don't want to do it that way

Comment: Yes but I just figured it out. For some reason it created another instance of the file located in a different folder and that was affecting it.  Thanks for your help